# Could not solve an equation in matlab (that has known solutions)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve a system of 3 equations with 3 variables in matlab.

Here's the matlab code:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

syms x y z
eq1 = 30 - ((30*sin(y) + (6032463447834141*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) - (30*sin(y)*((139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(72057594037927936*(((842441452475839123526592959619*cos(y)*sin(x))/10141204801825835211973625643008 + (30162317239170705*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/571740979893939208192 + (18097390343502423*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/285870489946969604096)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) + 3888617886914517/36028797018963968)))*((12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(z)*sin(x) + cos(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869 - (139651314883359*cos(x)*cos(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(sin(x)*sin(z) - cos(x)*cos(z)*sin(y)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 30*cos(x)*cos(y) == -(8922777075240197*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) - (30*sin(y)*((139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(9007199254740992*(((842441452475839123526592959619*cos(y)*sin(x))/10141204801825835211973625643008 + (30162317239170705*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/571740979893939208192 + (18097390343502423*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/285870489946969604096)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) + 3888617886914517/36028797018963968));
eq2 = ((30*sin(y) - (2751313666748167*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 - (139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(36028797018963968*(((13756568333740835*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/285870489946969604096 - (384224571217937317986432052953*cos(y)*sin(x))/5070602400912917605986812821504 + (8253941000244501*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/142935244973484802048)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 1085710309166423/18014398509481984)))*((139651314883359*cos(x)*cos(y))/140737488355328 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(z)*sin(x) + cos(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(sin(x)*sin(z) - cos(x)*cos(z)*sin(y)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 30*cos(x)*cos(y) + 30 == -(8964476491404667*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 - (139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(9007199254740992*(((13756568333740835*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/285870489946969604096 - (384224571217937317986432052953*cos(y)*sin(x))/5070602400912917605986812821504 + (8253941000244501*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/142935244973484802048)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 1085710309166423/18014398509481984));
eq3 = 30 - ((30*sin(y) - (5869842550983837*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)))/(72057594037927936*((5869842550983837*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/(72057594037927936*((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)) + 7567579956186207/72057594037927936)))*((278913769878129*cos(x)*cos(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(z)*sin(x) + cos(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469 - (10*13469^(1/2)*(sin(x)*sin(z) - cos(x)*cos(z)*sin(y)))/13469))/((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469) - 30*cos(x)*cos(y) == (8927287469964123*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)))/(9007199254740992*((5869842550983837*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/(72057594037927936*((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)) + 7567579956186207/72057594037927936));

equation_3_angles(1) = eq1;
equation_3_angles(2) = eq2;
equation_3_angles(3) = eq3;

fprintf('Trying to solve the equations (the function never finish)\n');
[x_solution, y_solution, z_solution] = solve(equation_3_angles,[x, y, z]);
```

The solve function never finishes.. So I can't get the solution.

There are solutions for the equations above.
The solutions are

- `(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)`
- `(x,y,z)=(0.523598775598299, 0, 0)`

But I need to get these solutions mathematically.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to add a [mcve], instead of a link to your complete code.

Comment: The code in the link is very minimal. I wrote it and documented it specifically for the stack overflow. 
It has nothing to do with my complete code which is a very big project.
I didn't write anything in the code that is not relevant to the question I posted. Please look at it again.

Comment: I Edited my question. Now the code is posted in the question.

Comment: That are quite large non-linear equations to solve. I'm afraid this is not possible mathematically. Why can't you use a numerical solver?

Comment: Are you talking about vpasolve? because if I change 'solve' to 'vpasolve' it always return the zeros solution (The only solution that I don't want).
Besides, my real equations are symbolic equations. In my project I'm trying to find x,y,z as expressions of other 'known' symbols. I just want to make sure it works for numbers before I move on to symbols.

Comment: If it's not possible mathematically how can a numerical solver help here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve them numerically with this script:

```
x0=[0.1 0.1 0.1]

sol=fsolve(@fun,x0)

function[obj]=fun(xx)
```

Calling this function

```
function[obj]=fun(xx)

x=xx(1);
y=xx(2);
z=xx(3);

eq1 = 30 - ((30*sin(y) + (6032463447834141*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) - (30*sin(y)*((139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(72057594037927936*(((842441452475839123526592959619*cos(y)*sin(x))/10141204801825835211973625643008 + (30162317239170705*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/571740979893939208192 + (18097390343502423*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/285870489946969604096)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) + 3888617886914517/36028797018963968)))*((12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(z)*sin(x) + cos(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869 - (139651314883359*cos(x)*cos(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(sin(x)*sin(z) - cos(x)*cos(z)*sin(y)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 30*cos(x)*cos(y) -( -(8922777075240197*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) - (30*sin(y)*((139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(9007199254740992*(((842441452475839123526592959619*cos(y)*sin(x))/10141204801825835211973625643008 + (30162317239170705*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/571740979893939208192 + (18097390343502423*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/285870489946969604096)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 - (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 + (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) + 3888617886914517/36028797018963968)));
eq2 = ((30*sin(y) - (2751313666748167*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 - (139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(36028797018963968*(((13756568333740835*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/285870489946969604096 - (384224571217937317986432052953*cos(y)*sin(x))/5070602400912917605986812821504 + (8253941000244501*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/142935244973484802048)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 1085710309166423/18014398509481984)))*((139651314883359*cos(x)*cos(y))/140737488355328 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(z)*sin(x) + cos(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869 + (10*15869^(1/2)*(sin(x)*sin(z) - cos(x)*cos(z)*sin(y)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 30*cos(x)*cos(y) + 30 -( -(8964476491404667*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((10*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/15869 - (139651314883359*cos(y)*sin(x))/140737488355328 + (12*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/15869))/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869)))/(9007199254740992*(((13756568333740835*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/285870489946969604096 - (384224571217937317986432052953*cos(y)*sin(x))/5070602400912917605986812821504 + (8253941000244501*15869^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/142935244973484802048)/((139651314883359*sin(y))/140737488355328 + (10*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/15869 - (12*15869^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/15869) - 1085710309166423/18014398509481984)));
eq3 = 30 - ((30*sin(y) - (5869842550983837*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)))/(72057594037927936*((5869842550983837*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/(72057594037927936*((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)) + 7567579956186207/72057594037927936)))*((278913769878129*cos(x)*cos(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(z)*sin(x) + cos(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469 - (10*13469^(1/2)*(sin(x)*sin(z) - cos(x)*cos(z)*sin(y)))/13469))/((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469) - 30*cos(x)*cos(y) -( (8927287469964123*(30*cos(y)*sin(x) + (30*sin(y)*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)))/(9007199254740992*((5869842550983837*((278913769878129*cos(y)*sin(x))/281474976710656 + (10*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*sin(z) + cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y)))/13469 - (12*13469^(1/2)*(cos(x)*cos(z) - sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)))/13469))/(72057594037927936*((10*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*cos(z))/13469 - (278913769878129*sin(y))/281474976710656 + (12*13469^(1/2)*cos(y)*sin(z))/13469)) + 7567579956186207/72057594037927936)));

obj=[eq1;eq2;eq3]

end
```

This is what I got, as expected

```
fsolve completed because the vector of function values is near zero
as measured by the default value of the function tolerance, and
the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient.

<stopping criteria details>

sol =
    0.5236    0.0000    0.0000
```

If you use `x0=[0 0 0]` as seed, the result is (as expected):

```
sol =
     0     0     0
```

But, the solution is extremely dependant of the initial guess (seed). For example, for `x0=[1 1 1]` the result is:

```
sol =
   -2.2063    3.0245    3.1109
```

In order to find the possible solutions, you can modify the script to perform a sweep like this:

```
n=5; %You can change this value for trying more points

x0=linspace(0,2*pi,n)
y0=linspace(0,2*pi,n)
z0=linspace(0,2*pi,n)

sol=zeros(n^3,3);
fval=zeros(n^3,3);
fval_flag=ones(n^3,1);

c=0;
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        for k=1:n
            c=c+1;
            [sol(c,:),fval(c,:)]=fsolve(@fun,[x0(i) y0(j) z0(k)]);
            %Check if the function evaluation is larger than 1e-6 because
            %this might not be a solution and set a flag
            if any(fval(c,:)>1e-6)
                fval_flag(c)=0;
            end
        end
    end
end

%Get only the solutions from 0 to 2*pi. This will list all the rows with
%this condition
[row,col]=find(sol<0 | sol>2*pi);
%Sort and get the unique rows with wrong values
row=unique(sort(row));
%Create a copy of the solution and remove this rows from the solution
sol2=sol;
sol2(row,:)=[];
fval_flag(row)=[];

%Show and compare the obtained solutions with its flag values (is the 4th
%column is 0 then it might not be a solution
out=[sol2 fval_flag]
```

This will remove the possible solutions outside the range `[0 2*pi]` and will show you the solutions for x,y,a and also a flag showing a 0 with values that are possibly not a solution because the equations are not close enought to 0 (I used a tolerance varue of `1e-6`).

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro,
Do you know if there's a way to get all the possible solutions?
and since the variables are angles, they all should be between 0 to 2*pi.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know there are so many solutions. and it seems that there are actually infinite solutions.

I think I made a mistake putting here the numerical equations since I thought it will help me to solve the symbolic equation which is the original problem I'm trying to solve.

I posted the symbolic equations together with the mathematical problem that I'm trying to solve. If you can, I'd really appreciate if you look at it.
Here's the post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187100/finding-rotation-of-3-given-lines-in-3d-until-intersection-with-3-other-given-li

Thanks